# Dygraphs: set static width (in pixels) between x-axis values

Tags: dygraphs

How can I set static width between x-axis values on my dygraphs-chart? For example, I need to an interval between x-axis values will be like 36px. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what the [`pixelsPerLabel` option](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#pixelsPerLabel) does:

> Number of pixels to require between each x- and y-label. Larger values
>   will yield a sparser axis with fewer ticks. This is set on a per-axis
>   basis.
>
> Type: integer Default: 70 (x-axis) or 30 (y-axes)

You may also want to set the `axisLabelWidth` option to shrink the `<div>`s that dygraphs uses for the x-axis labels:

```
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  axes: {
    x: {
      pixelsPerLabel: 36,
      axisLabelWidth: 30
    }
  }
});
```

The `pixelsPerLabel` setting is a *minimum*. dygraphs may decide to use more space to get nice label values. If you really want your ticks every 36 pixels, you'll need to use a custom ticker.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another question, Can I show each minute (x-axis) every 36 pixels, if I have 120 value per minute?